# how can i open a mpx project file and then save it as mpp project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-project, aspose, mpxj

I have an application in Asp .Net Mvc3, i am using the mpxj library for to generate a project file (with extension mpx). But this file not contain dates for Tasks, then i want to open the file with Ms Project and then save with the new format (Ms project create Dates for tasks). Detail is that i want to do it automatically. Is it possible? What is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that `interop` `MsOffice` in Asp.NET not is recommended http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757. 
But the need to automatically calculate dates, I am handling errors, and I am using `MsProject Interop`.  This is my code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application();
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
app.AskToUpdateLinks = false;

app.FileOpenEx(
        Server.MapPath("") + "\\sample.mpx",
        false,
        Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,
        PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadWrite, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project pj=app.ActiveProject;

app.CalculateAll(); //Para calcular las fechas

app.FileSaveAs(Server.MapPath("") + "\\sample.mpp",PjFileFormat.pjMPP, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing,           Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Import library `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject`.

See my code from an ASP.NET Web Forms. You can do the same with any version of ASP; you can also do it with ASP.NET Core, but that changes some small things.

1. If you noticed, I saved my file in path `c:\temp`
2. I take the file from the front as a variable `fu_upload` and make my process, then saved file and open it for read.

   ```
    ApplicationClass appclass = new ApplicationClass();

    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object mppfile = @"c:\Temp";
    if (fu_Upload.PostedFile.FileName.Contains(@"\"))
        mppfile += fu_Upload.PostedFile.FileName.Substring(fu_Upload.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\"), fu_Upload.PostedFile.FileName.Length - fu_Upload.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('\\'));// fu_Upload.PostedFiles[0].FileName;
    else
        mppfile += @"\" + fu_Upload.PostedFile.FileName;
    fu_Upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(mppfile.ToString());
    object oFormat = "sample.mpx";
    object oReadOnly = true;

    PathFile = mppfile.ToString();

    UploadFileToFileSpacePage(fu_Upload, PathFile);

    appclass.DisplayAlerts = false;
    //    var projectdoc ;
    appclass.FileOpen(mppfile, oReadOnly, Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjMergeType.pjDoNotMerge, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oFormat, oMissing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadOnly, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project project = appclass.ActiveProject;

    return project;
   ```